# Why use the data type 'double' instead of 'int?

Tags: java, double

There was another question that was similar I just didn't understand the answer very well.

So, I am in taking UIL Computer Science, (I am in high school), and I was taking a practice test. On the test, there was a question about double. Here it is:

```
double total = 0; 
for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++)     
    total += 0.5; 
    System.out.print(total)
```

What does double to this code? Please help, I am very confused on what double means!!

Comment: `(Java) (It isn't accepting any of my titles ,so I am just writing random stuff)` is a terrible title.  Please write a proper one.

Comment: How are you even trying to pass Java test without knowing of what is `double`?

Answer (score 0):

double is one of Java's 8 primitive data types, just like int, which you have also used in your code example. There are lots of sites that explain the eight primitive types in Java. Here is one:

http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/java-data.html

Answer (score 0):

A very basic explanation is that a `double` can be a number with a decimal point.

So with regards to the code you posted, because `total` is of type `double` it can be incremented by `0.5` after every loop `total += 0.5`. If `total` was of type `int` this would not be possible.

Also, you should really not give up so easily when looking for answers. This is a very basic question of which there are a multitude of sources with the answer. [Here is an example.](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/double_variables.html)

Best of luck with your studies.